# Структура БД, если у каждого производителя подкатегории своя структура таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, csv

Привет друзья!

Мучаюсь с данным вопросом уже почти двое суток..

Суть в том что есть сайт у которого 4 категории, в каждой категории ещё по 2 категории и в каждой категории множество производителей.

Всё работает через *.csv* файлы, т.к. много производителей и у каждого производителя свой прайс, который клиент закачивает через *csv* файл. Свой прайс – подразумевает разное количество колонок (у одного может быть 5, у другого производителя 10 и т.д.).

Всё бы ничего, но когда пошли файлы по *300 000K строк*, *memory_limit* в *256М* стал не выдерживать (больше не сделать). Понял что пора заняться переносом всей этой кухни на БД (mysql), но вот собственно сабж – у каждого же производителя своя структура csv, при том что я заранее о ней не знаю (клиент сам заливает csv).

Со своих идей, есть предложение создать две таблицы:

1. products_headers: id, brand_name, header, category, subcategory
2. products: id, brand_name, content

В первой хранить заголовки *csv* и связывать их со второй через поле *id*. Весь контент в *json* или *csv* формате, но это самое бредовое что могло только прийти.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами и знает решения?..

Comment: А почему бы не посмотреть в сторону NoSQL? Mongo бы неплохо подошел под эту задачу. Там как раз нет четкой схемы БД и можно при парсинге CSV файла создать нужный документ.

Comment: @Vartlok проблема в том что у них есть уже некоторые данные в БД MySQL, а хранить в двух БДхах данные, как-то не алё (

Comment: В проекте используем mysql и mongodb, ничего страшного в этом нет. Если вам нужна выборка по этой структуре, то храните в NoSQL, в противном случае сериализуйте данные и храните в MySQL.

Comment: @Invision хостинг не предоставляет MongoDB :( Спасибо за Ваши ответы, наверное выберем json + mysql.

Comment: А поддержки PostgreSQL случайно нет на хостинге?

Comment: Ваша задача и вправду решается документоориентированной NoSQL базой данных.

Comment: Подумайте о смене хостера, их сейчас слава Богу хватает.

Comment: @DmitriyFedin к сожалению и это нет(